# IONIC 2, setInterval keeps on running in background

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have read everywhere that Ionic Apps don't run in background by default, which is my requirement as well. (Tested on android)

In my app, I have a setInterval running which keeps on executing even in background (I waited for 15 mins)

I have not installed any background Plugins so far. Here is my plugin list

```
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
```

How did I test?

In my setinterval I have done a http request in which If there is an error of no internet, I show a toast of please turn device internet on. Then put the app in background. But that toast keeps on coming on other apps. (I put my internet off on my device)

Comment: I can confirm I tested this coincidentally yesterday it works in background. Not fully but like 75%.

Comment: can you add the code?

Comment: its nothing but a setinterval method calling an api service with success/failure